# Django forms not saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

when I trying to upload a file, the line form.save(), the image is being saved in the /media folder but the webpage is showing me an error (relation "project1_document" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "project1_document" ("description", "document", ...)

my `model_form_upload.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
      <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

my `models.py`

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='UserUploads/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import Document

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('description', 'document', )
```

error is occurred when I'm saving my form from my `views.py`.exactly at this line  [ forms.save() ] I'm getting an error [ relation "project1_document" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "project1_document" ("description", "document", ...) ]
my `views.py`:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from project1.forms import DocumentForm
    from .models import Document
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
    from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
        def model_form_upload(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(); #here
                    return redirect('home')
            else:
                form = DocumentForm()
            return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {
                'form': form
            })
```

my migrations file`0002_document.py`
from django.db import migrations, models
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('project1', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Document',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('description', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)),
            ('document', models.FileField(upload_to='UserUploads/')),
            ('uploaded_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

I don't know this is correct way or not but one solution worked for me by catching the exception: my `views.py` updated

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save();
            except:
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Please provide the entire traceback for the error

Comment: error is occurred when I'm saving my form from my views.py [ forms.save() ] exactly at this line I'm getting an error [ relation "project1_document" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "project1_document" ("description", "document", ...) ]

Comment: That isn't the **full traceback**. it's kind of important in this case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when there are changes in the models.py not yet reflected in the database.

In order to apply those changes you need to run
`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` every time you change your models

Comment: I have updated my migrations when I changed `models.py `. I had updated my migrations file `0002_document.py`.

Comment: What do you mean with "updated"? Did you change the file manually? Once you've run `migrate` you cannot modify your file, every migration is run only once, you need to create a new one every time. Also, can you add your entire model? Do you have the foreign key to document in your project model? And the most important question, did you run the `migrate` command, or only `makemigrations`?

Comment: No, I did not do it manually. I had done the complete migrations from cmd again and got a new migrations file. I had run the commands `python  manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py sqlmigrate` and then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I've copied your code and works perfectly on my machine. Documents are uploaded. Try to add your model to Django admin and see what fields are in there. Did you get error from the migrate command?

Comment: yeah, I had added my model to admin,`from django.contrib import admin`
`from .models import Movie , Document`
`admin.site.register(Movie)`
`admin.site.register(Document)` no I did not get any error in migrations.I had used try /exception blocks. to rectify the error.thanks @fran for your reply :)

Comment: Are you able to create a new document from there?

Comment: yeah, im able to create a new document from there?